# Error while installing libc6:i386

Tags: apt, package-management, dpkg

I am trying to install libc6:i386 but it is dumping this error:

```
LD_LIBRARY_PATH contains the traditional /lib directory,
but not the multiarch directory /lib/i386-linux-gnu.
It is not safe to upgrade the C library in this situation;
please remove the /lib/directory from LD_LIBRARY_PATH and
try again.
```

The output of `echo $LD_LIBRARY_PATH` is empty.
The full report of apt-install is as follows:

```
$ sudo apt install libc6:i386

Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
The following packages were automatically installed and are no longer required:
  bridge-utils libegl1-mesa libfwup1 libllvm9 ubuntu-fan
Use 'sudo apt autoremove' to remove them.
Suggested packages:
  glibc-doc:i386 locales:i386
The following NEW packages will be installed:
  libc6:i386
0 upgraded, 1 newly installed, 0 to remove and 39 not upgraded.
38 not fully installed or removed.
Need to get 0 B/2,550 kB of archives.
After this operation, 10.8 MB of additional disk space will be used.
Preconfiguring packages ...
(Reading database ... 515729 files and directories currently installed.)
Preparing to unpack .../libc6_2.27-3ubuntu1.2_i386.deb ...

LD_LIBRARY_PATH contains the traditional /lib directory,
but not the multiarch directory /lib/i386-linux-gnu.
It is not safe to upgrade the C library in this situation;
please remove the /lib/directory from LD_LIBRARY_PATH and
try again.

dpkg: error processing archive /var/cache/apt/archives/libc6_2.27-3ubuntu1.2_i386.deb (--unpack):
 new libc6:i386 package pre-installation script subprocess returned error exit status 1
Errors were encountered while processing:
 /var/cache/apt/archives/libc6_2.27-3ubuntu1.2_i386.deb
E: Sub-process /usr/bin/dpkg returned an error code (1)
```

Answer (score 0):

```
# sudo su
# export LD_LIBRARY_PATH=$LD_LIBRARY_PATH:/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu:/lib/i386-linux-gnu
# apt --fix-broken install
```

Comment: The # symbol (in bash) implies that the user is root, so there's no need to run `sudo su`. If you meant the user should run this, change the prompt to $.